# R shiny: Timevis output in modal dialogue

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog, timeline

How to show a timevis output in a modal dialogue in r shiny. Following the example from [reactivity in timevis package: passing selectinput variable to subgroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64725937/reactivity-in-timevis-package-passing-selectinput-variable-to-subgroup) I have tried to show the timeline in a modal dialogue. Thanks for any help.

The code:

```
library(shiny)
library(timevis)
library(dplyr)

# constructing data frame
pre_data <- data.frame(
  group      = as.integer(c(1,1,2,2)),
  content = c("Item one", "Item two",
              "Ranged item", "Ranged item two"),
  start   = c("2016-01-10", "2016-01-11",
              "2016-01-20", "2016-02-14"),
  end     = c(NA, NA, "2016-02-04", "2016-05-14")
)

# preparing for timevis
data <- pre_data %>% 
  arrange(group, start) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number())


ui <- fluidPage(
  # selectinput getting data from dataframe
  selectInput(inputId = "group", 
              label = "group", 
              choices = data$group),
  timevisOutput("timeline"),
  actionButton("show", "Show timeline in modal dialog")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # reactive input variable
  var_group <- reactive({input$group})
  
  # 
  output$timeline <- renderTimevis({
    req(var_group())
    data %>% 
      filter(group == as.integer(var_group())) %>% 
      timevis()
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$show, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Important message",
      timevisOutput("timeline"),
      easyClose = TRUE
    ))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43748316/show-datatableoutput-in-modal-in-shiny-app), you can use `bsModal` from the `shinyBS` package. I'm not sure if you can use `XOutput` in the normal shiny modal.

```
library(shiny)
library(timevis)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyBS)

# constructing data frame
pre_data <- data.frame(
  group      = as.integer(c(1,1,2,2)),
  content = c("Item one", "Item two",
              "Ranged item", "Ranged item two"),
  start   = c("2016-01-10", "2016-01-11",
              "2016-01-20", "2016-02-14"),
  end     = c(NA, NA, "2016-02-04", "2016-05-14")
)

# preparing for timevis
data <- pre_data %>% 
  arrange(group, start) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number())


ui <- fluidPage(
  # selectinput getting data from dataframe
  selectInput(inputId = "group", 
              label = "group", 
              choices = data$group),
  actionButton("show", "Show timeline in modal dialog"),
  bsModal("timeviesmodal", "Timeline", "show", size = "large",
          timevisOutput("timeline"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # reactive input variable
  var_group <- reactive({input$group})
  
  # 
  output$timeline <- renderTimevis({
    req(var_group())
    data %>% 
      filter(group == as.integer(var_group())) %>% 
      timevis()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```